# Changing Directory by Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to create a simple script to delete all the files from my Desktop(I am using  Ubuntu).

```
puts "Started at #{Time.now}"
Dir.chdir("/Desktop")
Dir.entries(".").each do |file|
    if file.to_s.include?("xlsx")
      puts "Deleting file #{file}" unless file == "." || file == ".."
      File.delete "#{Dir.pwd}/#{file}" unless file == "." || file == ".."
    end  
end
puts "Ended on #{Time.now}"
```

But when I generate the code it throws the below error:

> chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /Desktop
>   (Errno::ENOENT)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: not working! ` `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - ./Desktop (Errno::ENOENT)`

Comment: It should be `~/Desktop`. Also, `unless` clause is redundant, file cannot include `xlsx` (should be `.ends_with?('.xlsx')` btw) and equal to `'.'` simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks! It sill not working.  It shows the same error `'chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - ~/Desktop (Errno::ENOENT)`

Yes, I just want to remove all the xlsx file from the Desktop.

Comment: Nah. Stupid ruby does not understand tilde. Use: `Dir.chdir && Dir.chdir('Desktop')`.

Comment: It worked Thanks!  Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puts "Started at #{Time.now}"
Dir.chdir("#{ENV['HOME']}/Desktop")
Dir.entries(".").select { |file| file.ends_with?('.xlsx') }.each do |file|
  puts "Deleting file #{file}"
  File.delete "#{Dir.pwd}/#{file}"
end
puts "Ended on #{Time.now}"
```

Comment: This will only work if run from the home dir, better to use `"#{ENV["HOME"]}/desktop"`

Comment: @maxpleaner I have tested it, please note empty `Dir.chdir &&`.